# Why is iOS Xcode project giving error for missing OSX framework AVKit?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xcode5, xcode6

So my iOS project was working fine, then all of a sudden I am getting the following error when I try to run in simulator:

```
ld: framework not found AVKit for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And when I try to archive I get this error:

```
ld: framework not found AVKit for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

From what I can tell, AVKit is an OSX framework and not an iOS framework.

So why is my project suddenly confused and wanting an OSX framework, and do I convince it that it does not need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apparently AVKit is available in the iOS 8 SDK so I need to upgrade Xcode to version 6 in order to add it.

See this question: [Need help: 'Wrong Architecture' causing app to crash when launching in iOS 7 but works fine in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958232/need-help-wrong-architecture-causing-app-to-crash-when-launching-in-ios-7-but)

And it should be set as an Optional framework if you want to support iOS 7 and below as well.